# Message-Id header changing when sending via ActiveSync

Tags: outlook, activesync

I noticed that when sending mail from Outlook via ActiveSync or SMTP,
in some cases (not sure which), the Outlook server changes the *Message-Id* header on the way out.

This doesn't happen when sending via EWS using the ExtendFieldURI parameter.

Is it possible to guaranty that the Message-Id won't change when sending via ActiveSync or SMTP?

Notes:

1. The Message-Id is generated by the sending mail client
2. This header changes only when sending with ActiveSync or SMTP
3. Looking in the sent items folder, the Message-id is not changed. It is changed only at the receiving side.

Answer (score 2):

I work on Outlook.com. We have a feature that relies on rewriting the Message IDs on the server-side after the submitted message is stored in the mailbox. This is not the case for EWS at this time. There is no way to change this behavior.

Regards,
Sean

Comment: Is there a way to get the [re-written] message id at the sender side?

Comment: For future reference - Outlook's SMTP server responds with the new message id when sending.