# Why do Microsoft messageRule IDs periodically change

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server

I have a script that queries [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/messagerule?view=graph-rest-1.0) for the mail rules of each user. Each mail rule comes back with an ID which I then store for tracking purposes. However these rule IDs periodically change. I haven't been able to determine what causes this. Is there a predictable way to identify mail rules?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you aren't the only one to have this problem. This post has been open for over a year on MS's Q&A Board: [messageRule ID not constant?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/494029/messagerule-id-not-constant.html)

This answer may provide some insight as to why this is happening: [Message-Id header changing when sending via ActiveSync - Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46125254/4468380)

Unfortunately, it seems like this is a shortcoming of Outlook (and other MS systems for that matter). Perhaps getting more traction to this issue can finally get MS to shed more light on this...